# Add intellimouse support to a TMemo or TRichEdit component

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

How i can add  [intellimouse](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/34325) support to a TMemo or TRichEdit component

i am using Delphi XE

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must set the [`ScrollBars`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/StdCtrls.TMemo.ScrollBars) property to ssHorizontal, ssVertical or `ssBoth`  and add the [`IMouse`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/IMouse) unit to your project.

**UPDATE**

To avoid the memory leak caused by the `IMouse` unit you must add this code before you application exit (for example in the `finalization` part of your main unit).

```
  if Assigned(Mouse.PanningWindow) then
    Mouse.PanningWindow := nil;
```

Comment: +1 Just a shame that adding that unit to your project results in VCL memory leaks!

Comment: Really? Is there any QC regarding this?

Comment: @David, i put a workaround for the memory leak in the answer. ;)

Comment: Thanks, good work. I'd be inclined to place this code in the finalization of the unit that uses IMouse. That way you can't take one without the other. Really though, the memory leak is embarrassing. It's as if the folk at Emba don't routinely run with FastMM in memory leak tracking mode. I also don't think their developers routinely run with UAC.